# Laravel Eloquent - writing a select query based on related objects

Tags: php, laravel

Apologies for the slightly weird title, but I have a bit of a problem even writing my problem down to just one line, I hope at least somebody will understand what I write below.

I have 4 tables (and Laravel models of course) - scriptruns, executables, executablestatuses and scriptlogs (no, I did not name the tables).

'scriptruns' has a foreign key to 'executables' named 'executable_id', and the Scriptrun model has a executables() method.
'executables' has a FK to 'executablestatuses' called "executablestatus_id' (and the Executable model class has a executablestatus() method of course).
'executablestatuses' is a simple table which has an ID and a name (and other non-important stuff).
'scriptlogs' has a FK to 'scriptruns' called 'scriptrun_id' (and the Scriptlog model class has a scriptrun() method of course).

I have a view in which I want to display scriptuns, which have an executablestatus different from id:3 - name:'deleted', and have a log (meaning count($scriptrun->scriptlogs) > 0 ) and show the newest instance first. So how do I properly write a "select query" using Eloquent?

What I have done so far is I did

Scriptrun::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

which was followed by a foreach loop in which I checked if every scriptrun has an executable which has an executablestatus different from deleted and if the number of logs is > 0, and that's what I sent to the view. Yes, it's ugly as hell, and probably pretty far from being efficient, but it worked. The problem now however is that there are hundreds (soon too be thousands) of instances of \App\Scriptrun, meaning pagination is absolutely necessary, and this is where I am lost. If I use my "filtering" using the foreach loop I end up with an array and the paginate() method is not defined there, or I can try to implement my own pagination which is reinventing the wheel so to speak and would probably not be anywhere as efficient as the built in functionality.

Thanks for ANY help

Comment: Do you have relationships setup between your 4 models? If so, you should be able to do `ScriptRun::whereHas('executables', function($subQuery){ $subQuery->whereHas('executable_status', function($subSubQuery){ $subSubQuery->where('status', '!=', 'deleted'); } })->orderBy('created_at')->get();` (or similar) and avoid the foreach loop entirely. Then you can also paginate that, etc etc. It would be super helpful if you could post the relevant parts of your models (class and relationships, at a minimum)

Comment: You are GREAT! Your comment wasn't 100% correct but it kicked me to the correct direction

Comment: Excellent :) Looks good! Yeah, anytime you can use relationship-querying functions instead of loops, try to; it's much more efficient and (generally) cleaner. Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Tim Lewis I was able to do it.
The correct solution for me was

```
 $runs = Scriptrun::whereHas('executable', function($subQuery) {
            $subQuery->whereHas('executablestatus', function ($subSubQuery) {
                $subSubQuery->where('id', '!=',  (\App\Executablestatus::deletedStatus())->id);
            });
        })
            ->whereHas('logs')
            ->orderBy('scriptruns.created_at', 'desc')
            ->paginate(15);
```